# "more profitable than that" vs "more profitable than that one"

Tags: determiners

> This company is **more profitable than that**.
>
> This company is **more profitable than that one**.

Are both sentences natural, or only the second one?

Comment: If the context is comparing Company A with Company B, the first sentence is not natural-sounding.  The second sentence is fine.  I personally would suggest: "This company is more profitable than **the other one**."

Comment: If you aren't comparing two companies, the first sentence is natural as a reply when someone says "The company had a 3% return on investment last year." There, *that* refers to the statement about its profitability.

Comment: Yes, they are both natural. However, they are not interchangeable. They would be used in different contexts.